# [NSManagedObject sayHello]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I try to extend NSManagedObject.
Using XCode I created MyBox.m and MyBox.h (directly from the xcdatamodel file).

Then I modified these files:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface MyBox : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * endDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * globalId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * startDate;

-(NSString *)sayHello;

@end
```

and

```
#import "MyBox.h"
@implementation MyBox

@dynamic endDate;
@dynamic globalId;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic startDate;

-(NSString *)sayHello {
    return @"hello";
}  

@end
```

I can fetch all myBoxes

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"MyBox" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSMutableArray *myBoxes = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

but later I call

```
MyBox *myBox = [myBoxes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    [myBox sayHello];
```

it compiles but then I get

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject sayHello]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e73fc0'
```

If I only read a value like

```
NSLog(@"%@", myBox.name);
```

it works

I found similar problems here, but no solution.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You probably forgot to set the class of the entity to `MyBox` at the coredata editor.

Comment: I have set Entity->Name = Entity->Class = "MyBox" in the coredata editor. Do I have to set some other properties?

Comment: Hmm that's strange. No that should be enough... Do you have multiple versions maybe?

Comment: I agree with Alladinian. If the entity class is set to MyBox then this should work. But the error message clearly states that `myBox` is a *only* a NSManagedObject. Perhaps NSLog the `myBoxes` array directly after fetching and check the class.

Comment: Have you tried to clean in Xcode? Problems with Core Data model cached at some level are often solved just by cleaning.

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([myBox class]))` in the function where you try to call `sayHello` to find out what kind of object `myBox` actually is.

Comment: Is the class with the method that calls `[myBox sayHello]` in the same project as the Core Data classes?

Comment: That was the Problem, ChrisH, the Class was in the correct Folder, but not part of the Project... I'm new in XCode and added the file the wrong way. Thank You!

Comment: I've done a rename refactor of the class and that caused the entity's class field in the core data editor to be emptied.

Answer (score 21):

I've just got the same issue. Solved it by changing class name to the name of my  NSManagedObject subclass in `myApp.xcdatamodeld -> configurations -> default -> entities -> myEntity`.

Comment: Damn, I always forget this thing.

Comment: I used Xcode 8 objective c Editor->Create NSManagedSubclass and in the Configuration it has periods on the front of all my entities which caused the same problem, but renaming them so it matched the autogenerated code fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have set the class name correctly on the `MyBox` entity, I would guess that the app has an older version of your Core Data managed object model. Clean your build and delete the app on the simulator/device for good measure. To be 100% sure, also delete your derived data folder.

If it doesn't work after that, I'll bet that you haven't set the entity class name correctly. Print out your `NSEntityDescription` and make sure it is what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

**For Swift 5.0**

This issue is present when you create the CoreData object in this way:

```
let object = CoreDataClass()
print(object.someProperty) // this is emit crash
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the right class name set in xcdatamodeld, but I didn't include the class's .m file in my target. I had to click on the .m on the left sidebar, then check the correct box on the right sidebar under Target Membership.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Xcdatamodel.

I had the wrong xcdatamodel. It's a super dumb mistake but when you assume the latest model is 27 but your coworker changed it to 28 and you added your properties to model 27, it happens.You get these kind of errors and you assume it's something wrong with your Core Data model but it's simply your xcdatamodel number.

Gotta love programming =_=.